# Sql performance issues

Tags: sql-server

I've got a reasonably sized database table (currently around a million rows).  The structure is basically this:

```
int id auto inc.
int emailId FK
int userId FK
int status
```

user table is essentially

```
int id auto inc.
varchar(500) email
```

I'm adding as many of these as fast as physically possible, but before adding them I need to check whether 'email' has already been sent to or not (it's possible for user to have duplicate emails.  If I try and sent to one that already exists, then status gets set to 4 instead of 0.

Anyway.  This currently works fine.  I can insert around 100 per second to start off with, but after a while (around 8000 inserts) it basically grinds to a halt.  If I reindex the database it picks up again, but why is it grinding to a halt in the first place?  It takes ages to update the index.

Comment: Would making name part of a primary key make it faster?  Then if an insert returns an error you set status to 4.  Not sure, just an idea...

Comment: Not exactly sure on your algorithm either... where are you getting your data from and writing it to?

Comment: I've tried a better example - sending emails to users, but not wanting to send multiple emails to one email address.  Email can't be made primary key in this instance no

Comment: Can you share the query you're using to insert and check if it has already been sent? Is it one query or two? Also tell us how you have the table indexed.

Comment: do you have a unique index on `email`?

Comment: Post a Query Plan for the slow-running query, and please supply complete DDL for objects referenced by said query.

Comment: If you have SSMS from object explorer you should be able to find the tables and right click "Script Table As" --> "Create to" --> "New Query Editor" to get the create table statements.

Comment: Probably your index becomes fragmented. Btw, what kind of index you are updating - I don't see any here...